# On Facebook like button on my site, how to disable "post to Facebook" button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, iframe

How can I disable the `Post to Facebook` button? It's very annoying.

I do not want to use an iframe version of the `like` code., as the following wouldn't work:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) { })
```

Can it be done with CSS or in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

you can manually hide the comment box by adding the following CSS code to your theme:

Simplest fix to hide the comment box after Facebook Like (XFBML version not the iframe one) is as given:

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget iframe.fb_ltr {
display: none !important;}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/XKcCB/)

[credits](http://blog.nicolasgrenie.com/index.php?post/Disable-comment-box-on-Facebook-like-button)

Answer (score -1):

[Facebook Developers page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) has a pretty good description of everything you'll need.

If you don't want to use an iframe, perhaps make a "Like" button of your own that simply links users to your Facebook page?

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/yourLink/Here"><img src="likeBtn.png" alt="Like Us On Facebook!" /></a>
```